# Getting error:The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4]]

Tags: java, android

All of my code is working perfect when I have these dependencies

```
   //noinspection GradleCompatible
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4' }
```

but when I add

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1'
```

It shows me error that :-

**Error:The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.**

I have already tried updating my gms library but when I do that I will need to make several changes to the code to meet the new release requirements. I am looking for a quick solution of solving it .

The current versions I am using are mentioned below :-

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Comment: Check whether the `google()` is appear before `jcenter()` in the list of repositories in project' gradle file.

Comment: yes thats the arrangement `repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    } `

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
```

instead of this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```

Comment: what I have already mentioned in my question if I use these it will ask me to make changes to the code as some new methods are implemented in new releases and old one are excluded. I am looking for simple solution.