# Error:In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[11.0.4]")

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle

I am Using these dependencies , I changed my places version so It shows me error also I wanted to use google places 16.0.0 version.

Dependencies I am using

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
```

Error I am getting :

> Error:In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[11.0.
>   4]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
>
> Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.0.4 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[11.0.4], b
>   ut play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.
>
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
>   ifact with the issue.

```
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-places@16.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@11.0.4
```

> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
>   endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
>   build.gradle file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error:The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at \[\[11.0.4,11.0.4\]\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307104/getting-errorthe-library-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-basement-is-being)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your **app** folder and open `build.gradle`,

or `platforms/android/app/build.gradle` **for phonegap app's**

add this to end of file:

`googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true`

Comment: is it a temporary solution?

Comment: @zafer I don't know, phonegap stuff, it will take a long time to solve...